# mapView:rendererForOverlay delegate method never called when addOverlay is called on MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I created a `MapViewController` class with a scene that has an `MKMapView` in the storyboard. The MKMapView has an outlet `mapView` to `MapViewController`, and the delegate is set to `MapViewController` in the storyboard. The `MapViewController` is a `MKMapViewDelegate`, and I implemented the optional delegate method `mapView:rendererForOverlay`, and some other ones.

In `viewDidAppear`, I call `addMapOverlay`, defined as:

```
  func addMapOverlay() {
    let overlayRect = MKMapRectMake(
      44.97077, -93.2864435,
      0.1, 0.1)

    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.97087, -93.2865435)

    let overlay = MapOverlay(coordinate: coordinate, rect: overlayRect)

    print("adding overlay with level...")
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.addOverlay(overlay, level: .AboveRoads)
  }
```

Even though the delegate is set in the storyboard, I tried to see if would help if I set it here as well. (No difference.)

I implement the delegate methods as such:

```
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

  func mapViewWillStartRenderingMap(mapView: MKMapView) {
    print("mapViewWillStartRenderingMap...")
  }

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didAddOverlayViews overlayViews: [AnyObject]) {
    print("mapView:didAddOverlayViews...")
  }

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay)
    -> MKOverlayRenderer {
      print("mapView:rendererForOverlay")

      if overlay is MapOverlay {
        let image = UIImage(named: "main_map_overlay")
        let overlayView = MapOverlayView(overlay: overlay, overlayImage: image!)

        return overlayView
      }

      return MKPolylineRenderer()
  }

}
```

I am supposed to see the UIImage in the mapView with the coordinates, but I don't. The problem is that `mapView:rendererForOverlay` never gets called. What am missing? My only output is:

```
adding overlay with level...
mapViewWillStartRenderingMap...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured out the answer to my problem. Turns out, `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.97087, -93.2865435)` is not the correct way to make the coordinate in this case. It's wrong one way or another, and as a result, adding the overlay silently fails without any helpful information. I did the following and it's fine now:

```
let parkTopLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(
  latitude: 44.972189,
  longitude: -93.287307))
let parkBottomRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(
  latitude: 44.967810,
  longitude: -93.28186))

let overlayRect = MKMapRectMake(
  parkTopLeft.x,
  parkTopLeft.y,
  parkBottomRight.x - parkTopLeft.x,
  parkBottomRight.y - parkTopLeft.y)

let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
  overlayRect.origin.x + overlayRect.size.width / 2,
  overlayRect.origin.y + overlayRect.size.height / 2)

let overlay = MapOverlay(coordinate: coordinate, rect: overlayRect)

mapView.addOverlay(overlay, level: .AboveRoads)
```